# Curl rest API to a second site in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to display a result from a rest API GET request, for example, "http://ifconfig.co/ip/" on my page.  However, I am running into many different errors, and just cannot seem to get it down. 
Her is what I have so far:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', 'https://ifconfig.co/ip', true);

req.withCredentials = false;            

req.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );


req.send();

document.write(req);
document.write(req.responseText);
document.write(req.responseXML);
```

In the javascript console it says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ifconfig.co/ip. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I am very new to javascript, can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` message means that the server is configured not to accept requests from the client's domain. Here's a great article on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS